# collection_select could not pull up list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I was wondering if anybody can help me with this small issue that i am facing.. I am trying to fix my collection_select function on my "address" edit controller.. in my views

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@address) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :customer_id, @customer.id %>

<%= f.label :customer_id %>
<%= f.text_field :customer_id, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

.
.
.

<%= f.label :owner_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :owner_id, @owners, :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'no owners', :prompt => true}, class: 'form-control' %>

.
.
.
<%= f.submit "Edit address", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

in my controller

```
def edit
@address = Address.find(params[:id])
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@owners = Owner.where(customer_id: @customer.id)
end
```

This can't work as there will be no owners showing up even thought i have already related them to the specific customer using customer_id in the owners table.

i have tried to change my controller edit code to:

```
def edit
@address = Address.find(params[:id])
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@owners = Owner.where(customer_id: 75)
end
```

and this WORKS, as it pulls all owners with customer_id: 75

I have even changed the link into the edit form to include the customer_id into the params like below:

```
<%= link_to "", edit_address_path(address, :customer_id => @customer.id), remote: true, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-edit" %>
```

Can anyone help me? will greatly appreaciate as i know it might be just a small error on my coding part.

Comment: Try to compare sql statements for  `Owner.where(customer_id: 75)` and  `Owner.where(customer_id: @customer.id)`. You can use for this `.to_sql`

Comment: I think your `@customer` should be `Customer.find(params[:customer_id])`

Answer (score 0):

able to solve my problem after entered code as below:

```
def edit
  @address = Address.find(params[:id])
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @owners = Owner.where(customer_id: params[:customer_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render partial: 'address_edit' }
  end
end
```

Comment: I mentioned that in the comment. However, you wouldn't be needing the `@customer` variable anymore, if you're going this route, however to maintain integrity in the app, it may be useful to have it as `find` will raise an error if record wasn't found

Comment: thanks so much for your help! will try the find method in my code.